# Is there any evidence for the validity of RNA/DNA supplements?

Tags: dna, rna, health

Is there any evidence for the validity of RNA/DNA supplements?

I've recently been seeing advertisements for RNA and DNA health supplements in the form of a pill, which claim to perform some rather miraculous functions within the body, though I can find no scientific validity behind this. There are some very respectable companies including Holland and Barrett selling this stuff and I can't see how this would provide any health benefits.

Are there any studies on this? If not, may someone care to speculate if there could be any health benefits to RNA/DNA supplements or is this just a terrible gimmick?

Comment: I skimmed through [this website](https://genotopia.scienceblog.com/406/dna-supplements-may-be-secret-of-longer-healthier-life/) and couldn't help but laugh at this: *Results of a bold new study from Kashkow University’s School of DNA and Medicine, expected to begin next year, were announced yesterday. They have been called a “breakthrough” and a “game-changer” by some of the leading scientists on the proposed study.* Aside from the fact that it makes no sense... [Kashkow University?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_cow)

Comment: haha! Brilliant. I especially remark at the comments of Cyrus Tosine

Comment: Says it all really. I'm just looking for any particular papers that conclusively refute it as idiots are being taken advantage of

Comment: @canadianer Where did you find this blog? It's incredible. Also "Credulity, WI": where people are incredulous? (of course there is no such town, unfortunately - I'd love to live there) "University of California at Boulder" - one of the most covert of all University of California schools... And where Cyrus Tosine is about to say it could help people "concen" ---trate? Seems either Cyrus or the author really need this product! Really truly brilliant piece, rivals anything in the Onion.

Comment: @Charlie The burden of proof is on the claimant; I don't expect there to be a lot of research based solely on refuting a ludicrous idea.

Comment: Yes I suppose. It however bothers me that this is being sold not only in dodgy online markets but stores people should be able to trust.

Comment: The website that canadianer linked to is meant to be satirical about these useless supplements. Despite that, comments left on the site still shows people think he's saying DNA/RNA supplements are good. Love his wit!

Comment: It didn't take me too long to realise it was satirical